# Inserting values from a dictionary in a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to data science and python. I am having trouble trying to fill values in columns of a table.

There is a table with rows device_id, age, gender, group + other columns.

I also have a dictionary consisting of device_id values as keys and a list of gender, age and group values {device_id: [gender, age, group]}

I am trying to iterate through the table and check the device_id of each row against the key value in the dictionary. On match, I intend to to assign the values in the relevant columns.

However I am not able to do that. Can someone show the way ahead??

Thanks

Comment: Please add a sample dictionary and the structure of your dataframe

Comment: "On match, I intend to to assign the values in the relevant columns."--sounds like you want to merge the table and the dictionary data.  This is easily done in Pandas with the table and dictionary as Dataframes. This could be illustrated if you provided example data for your table and dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Simplest way**

Use don't have to iterate to dictionary, you can directly do like below

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

dict = {
    #deviceid : [gender, age, group]
    "device_1" : ["m", 25, "group_1"],
    "device_2" : ["f", 22, "group_2"],
    "device_3" : ["f", 20, "group_2"],
    "device_4" : ["m", 80, "group_6"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
print(df)

#Output
#  device_1 device_2 device_3 device_4
#0        m        f        f        m
#1       25       22       20       80
#2  group_1  group_2  group_2  group_6
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample**

```
m = sample_df['Col1'].isin(sample_list)
sample_df[m].groupby('Col1')['Col2'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Returns:    {101: ['NJ', 'NJ', 'NJ'], 105: ['CA', 'CA'], 112: ['NB']}